# Using Java - Parsing REST response

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am getting a REST response from Alfresco like below:

```
{
  "list": {
    "pagination": {
      "count": 2,
      "hasMoreItems": false,
      "totalItems": 2,
      "skipCount": 0,
      "maxItems": 100
    },
    "entries": [
      {
        "entry": {
          "createdAt": "2021-07-28T16:01:52.607+0000",
          "isFolder": false,
          "isFile": true,
          "createdByUser": {
            "id": "admin",
            "displayName": "Administrator"
          },
          "modifiedAt": "2021-07-28T16:01:53.616+0000",
          "modifiedByUser": {
            "id": "admin",
            "displayName": "Administrator"
          },
          "name": "site1-export.zip",
          "id": "9591936a-82ac-4acc-a75c-29dbaffcae77",
          "nodeType": "cm:content",
          "content": {
            "mimeType": "application/zip",
            "mimeTypeName": "ZIP",
            "sizeInBytes": 22089,
            "encoding": "UTF-8"
          },
          "parentId": "9b211145-5359-4d69-9cbc-7247ba2def21"
        }
      },
      {
        "entry": {
          "createdAt": "2021-07-27T15:58:20.655+0000",
          "isFolder": false,
          "isFile": true,
          "createdByUser": {
            "id": "admin",
            "displayName": "Administrator"
          },
          "modifiedAt": "2021-07-27T15:58:20.655+0000",
          "modifiedByUser": {
            "id": "admin",
            "displayName": "Administrator"
          },
          "name": "zzTestPdf.pdf",
          "id": "58833967-6c26-448a-8be1-9387312028e1",
          "nodeType": "customprefixemp:employee_custom_type",
          "content": {
            "mimeType": "application/pdf",
            "mimeTypeName": "Adobe PDF Document",
            "sizeInBytes": 8037,
            "encoding": "UTF-8"
          },
          "parentId": "9b211145-5359-4d69-9cbc-7247ba2def21"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is how I am using jayway

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(theUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
JSONObject obj_JSONObject = new JSONObject(response.getBody()).getJSONObject("list");
Configuration cf = Configuration.builder().options(Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS).build();
DocumentContext ctx = JsonPath.using(cf).parse(obj_JSONObject.toString());
```

Using jayway I am getting the ids and iterating like below:

```
    List<String> objListItemsId = ctx.read("$.entries[*].entry.id");
    for (String fileId : objListItemsId) {
     logger.info("FileID  - " + fileId);
     //logger.info("What should I do here??: " + fileId + "_" +  fileName + "_" +  nodeType + "_" +  mimeType + "_" +  mimeTypeName);
    }
```

**Question 1:**
I need other details too. So, how can I get the values for other params like - `name`, `nodeType`, `mimeType` and `mimeTypeName`? I want to print these values in one line for-each `entry`. I am open for any solution.

Update:
For now, I am using this (dirty) way:

```
List<String> objListItemsId = ctx.read("$.entries[*].entry.id");
List<String> objListItemsName = ctx.read("$.entries[*].entry.name");
List<String> objListItemsNodeType = ctx.read("$.entries[*].entry.nodeType");
List<String> objListItemsContent = ctx.read("$.entries[*].entry.content.mimeType");

for (int listlen = 0; listlen < objListItemsId.size(); listlen ++) {
    System.out.println(objListItemsId.get(listlen) + "," + objListItemsName.get(listlen)+ "," +objListItemsNodeType.get(listlen) + "," + objListItemsContent.get(listlen));
}
```

**Question 2:** Is there a better way to achieve above?

Comment: When you say, jayway, I suppose you're using `json-path`?

From skimming https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath, and understanding what it's for - used for querying JSON, you seem to be doing it the right way. 

As for another option, you can try and parse the JSON into a Java object and traverse from there.

Comment: Yes as jsonpath. Updated my question with more info @nmina. Please see if that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a better way to do it although I dont know the type of `ctx` but Im assuming it is some sort of serde library. Most serde libraries allow you to deserialize to a given object.
To improve your solution:

- Create a class called `Entry`. It'll look something like:

```
public class Entry {
    String createdAt;
    String name;
    String id;
    // add other members from API
}
```

- Then you can do:

```
//this will depend on serde library your are using. Read its docs. 
List<Entry> objListItemsId = ctx.read("$.entries[*].entry", Entry.class);
```

It'll deserialize everything you want in `Entry` instance.

**UPDATE**

To further simplify your parsing, you can get rid of `entry` within your `entries` arrays. So instead of having

```
"entries": [
      {
        "entry": {
```

You can have

```
"entries": [
    {
        // entry 1 details
    },
    {
        // entry 2 details
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Looks promising @Boss Man. Sure will give it a try. Thanks for your time and effort.